SQL - Stack multiple substrings in one column
I am looking to stack multiple substrings in one column. I am looking for alternatives to UNION ALL because my real data is massive and there are over 30 occurrences of sub strings for each row.
Below code parse out the substrings for me but create columns for each sub string. I am looking to stack those smp and smp_Num under one column. I tried using inner join and unpivot but it didn't work for me. I am using DB2.
SELECT Prod_Typ, 
    SUBSTR(Product, 1, 3) as Smp,
        SUBSTR(Product, 4, 4) as Smp_Num,
    SUBSTR(Product, 8, 3) as Smp1,
    SUBSTR(Product, 11, 4) as Smp_Num1,
        SUBSTR(Product, 15, 3) as Smp2,
    SUBSTR(Product, 18, 4) as Smp_Num2,
        SUBSTR(Product, 22, 3) as Smp3,
        SUBSTR(Product, 25, 4) as Smp_Num3,
FROM my_table

My data looks like this.



Prod_Typ
Product




11789
AAD3241HHA3261UUB    MNN4567


11790
TTN7689KJI    FSS9980



What I am looking for my data to look like:



Prod_Typ
Smp
Smp_Num




11789
AAD
3241


11789
HHA
3261


11789
UUB



11789
MNN
4567


11790
TTN
7689


11790
KJI



11790
FSS
9980




The client you're using doesn't matter, but the database does. From your previous question, which had another approach already, you are using DB2?

I would strongly suggest not storing data like this. Combining multiple pieces of meaningful information together into a single column creates all kinds of headaches down the road, even more so when you have repeating groups embedded. You'll be much better off using a child table for those repeating groups, each row of which should break out your data into separate columns each with their own appropriate datatype.

@AlexPoole Yes, it is a DB2 data

You can use:
WITH positions (prod_typ, product, spos) AS (
  SELECT prod_typ, product, 1
  FROM   my_table
UNION ALL
  SELECT prod_typ, product, spos + 7
  FROM   positions
  WHERE  spos + 7 <= LENGTH(product)
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY prod_typ SET order_id
SELECT Prod_Typ, 
       SUBSTR(product, spos,     3) AS smp,
       SUBSTR(product, spos + 3, 4) AS Smp_Num
FROM   positions

or, from Oracle 12:
SELECT Prod_Typ, 
       SUBSTR(product, n * 7 - 6, 3) AS smp,
       SUBSTR(product, n * 7 - 3, 4) AS Smp_Num
FROM   my_table
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT LEVEL AS n
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= LENGTH(product)/7
       )

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE my_table(Prod_Typ, Product) AS
SELECT 11789, 'AAD3241HHA3261UUB    MNN4567' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11790, 'TTN7689KJI    FSS9980' FROM DUAL 

Both output:



PROD_TYP
SMP
SMP_NUM




11789
AAD
3241


11789
HHA
3261


11789
UUB
    


11789
MNN
4567


11790
TTN
7689


11790
KJI
    


11790
FSS
9980



Oracle fiddle

If you are using DB2 then you can use the first query without the SEARCH clause:
WITH positions (prod_typ, product, spos) AS (
  SELECT prod_typ, product, 1
  FROM   my_table
UNION ALL
  SELECT prod_typ, product, spos + 7
  FROM   positions
  WHERE  spos + 7 <= LENGTH(product)
)
SELECT Prod_Typ, 
       SUBSTR(product, spos,     3) AS smp,
       SUBSTR(product, spos + 3, 4) AS Smp_Num
FROM   positions

DB2 fiddle
